How do I receive a non primitive object as query parameter?
I'm trying to receive a nontrivial query parameter object. At the moment I'm doing this via a json-encoded string since objects seem to be assumed to arrive in the body in fastapi, so I've had to do something like this on the server:
class MyParam(pydantic.BaseClass):
  param1: list[str]
  param2: typing.Dict[str, SomeOtherPydanticType]

@router.get("/my/route")
def get_vhist_snap_pnl(
    param: pydantic.types.Json = fastapi.Query(
        ...,
        description="json-encoded dictionary",
    )
) -> str:
    obj = MyParam(param)

    ...

    return 'hello world'

I can use param to construct an instance of MyParam as above, but it would be nice for fastapi to do this for me directly in the function declaration because I'd get better swagger docs and it would be less code to write. How can I do this?

Supporting Pydantic models for non-body request parameters is included in the FastAPI's roadmap (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/10370).

You can get the actual string which is in json format from Query, then model_validate_json it to get your MyParam object:
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyParam(BaseModel):
    param1: list[str]
    param2: dict[str, SomeOtherPydanticType]


async def get_param(
    json_str: Annotated[str, Query(description="json-encoded dictionary")],
) -> MyParam:
    return MyParam.model_validate_json(json_str)


@router.get("/my/route")
def get_vhist_snap_pnl(param: Annotated[MyParam, Depends(get_param)]):
    print(param.param1)
    print(param.param2)


I don't want to return MyParam though, I want it to be read in from the query parameters

@quant I forgot to import Depends. It's now going to read it from query parameters then decode that read str and create a MyParam object. Isn't it what you want?

Indeed I created a dependency which injects what you need to your path operation function.
